# Send a file from PC to Arduino using HC-06 module

Tags: arduino-uno, python, hc-06

I want to send a file from my Laptop using its own Bluetooth transmitter to Arduino. Arduino has HC-06 module as receiver.Arduino has SD Card fore store the file.
I was able to send bytes using Python application.
How to send a file using a Python application to Arduino?

Comment: What kind of file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open the file in `rb` mode in your Python code.
- Since the Arduino SoftSerial RX buffer is 64 bytes in size, sending 60 bytes per packet to the Arduino is okay. You basically call `out = file.read(60)` in python to read 60 bytes from the file and then write these bytes to the Arduino with `ser.write(out)`. You can have the python program wait for acknowledgement from the Arduino, perhaps indicating how many bytes it actually received (after a given timeout period) or what byte was last received. This is just very minor error detection.
- The Arduino saves the 60-byte packet to an array and writes everything at once to a file on the SD card, that you've already opened.
- After receiving acknowledgement from the Arduino, the Python program reads the next 60 bytes and forwards to the Arduino like before. Continue till the file is exhausted. You could send some sort of signature byte to inform the Arduino that no more bytes are coming and to close the file. Alternatively, a timeout period can be used.

Note: It'll be more efficient if you wrote to the SD card in chunks, where the chunk size is a factor of the card's sector size. 64 bytes is the highest you can do with the default RX buffer size, but thats living dangerously as you risk buffer overflow if anything goes bump.
This can be avoided though, by reading bytes from the RX buffer and into your own array, as soon as they arrive.

Chunks of 32 bytes is safer but it will naturally take longer to send the whole file. Test and judge for yourself.

Comment: Draining the buffer shouldn't be a challenge if the Arduino is ready, and it may be more useful to operate in chunks that divide evenly into a sector on the card.

Comment: @ChrisStratton like 64 bytes, you mean? I just used 60 for some redundancy. Its easier to test this way and if it all works, optimize it. I'll edit though.

Comment: I'd personally be trying to avoid the situation where the serial buffer is holding much at all, by making sure the program is able to drain data promptly.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Just realized I strayed off...I get your point.